# Drop-down Menu on Hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a drop-down menu that expands when I hover over or click on gallery in the menu bar. I thought I knew what I was doing, but it is not working so obviously I am doing something wrong. If anyone sees my mistake please let me know.

This is what I currently have:

```css
#menubar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

#options {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 1%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

#options-gallery {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#options-gallery:hover #galleries {
  display: grid;
}

a:link {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

a:visited {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#galleries {
  display: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 30;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#gallery-videos {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'sans-serif';
  animation: entranceAnimation 0.5s forwards 0.5s linear;
}

#gallery-videos a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 35;
}

#gallery-design {
  background-color: #00CC52;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'sans-serif';
  animation: entranceAnimation 0.5s forwards 0.4s linear;
}

#gallery-design a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 35;
}

#gallery-other {
  background-color: #0541D8;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'sans-serif';
  animation: entranceAnimation 0.5s forwards 0.3s linear;
}

#gallery-other a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 35;
}

@keyframes entranceAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-150%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar" style="width: 100%">
  <div id="options">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li id="options-gallery">Gallery</li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="galleries">
  <div id="gallery-videos">
    <a href="gallery-videos"></a>
    <h1>Videos</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="gallery-design">
    <a href="gallery-design"></a>
    <h1>Design</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="gallery-other">
    <a href="gallery-other"></a>
    <h1>Other</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed you have `style=100%` on `#menubar` as well as defining it in your css. This is not part of your problem just wanted to note that. Also `#galleries` has `display: none`. Is that supposed to be set by default? If so, how do you plan on removing it to see the code since there is no server side code, media queries or javascript attached to the question?

Comment: @RickSibley the `#menubar` style was just left over from when I had all my css in the html file, thanks for catching that. I tried setting the `#galleries` to `display: none` as I was trying to replicate what I saw [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_text). If that is not how it is supposed to be done that might be my problem.

Comment: Ok is see. Shouldn't your layout look more like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWHM8VJ8WX5F) for that that kind of drop down? Note: it is dumbed down so I didn't add all your styling.

Comment: Would that still work if I wanted [this](https://kevinlong021.github.io/gallery/) to dropdown and overlay the whole page?

Comment: I was in the process of trying to build-out what I think your looking for. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWHP7BI2L2JM) is as far as I got. Take a look and let me know if there are any principles im missing. Slowly we can get closer to your end goal.

Comment: @RickSibley That is almost what I want. I made [a few changes](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWHRKMQK67RA) mostly just to the layout. Is there a way to get the options to slide in individually like [this](https://kevinlong021.github.io/gallery/) starting with the right and moving to the left? I tried doing it but that is where things seem to stop working for me.

Comment: Sorry I had went home for the day. Is [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWII8FL1H1MP) what you are looking for? I forgot to mention that I cannot access your website from my location so some of the stuff you try and show me I can't see. You explain it well enough for me to get and idea though.

Comment: @RickSibley That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Anytime! enjoy the rest of your day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the links in the comments will last forever, so in case you ever want to look back at this for reference here is the answer:

```css
html,
body,
.flex {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /*change font family*/
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ccc;
  /*change color*/
}

.navbar .navlink {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  /*change font size*/
  padding: 14px 16px;
  /*change padding*/
  color: black;
  /*change text color */
}

.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  /*change padding*/
  font-size: 16px;
  /*change font size*/
}

.navbar .navlink:hover,
.subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  /*change color*/
}

.subnav-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  /*change color*/
}

#galleries {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#g-videos {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

#g-design {
  background-color: #00CC52;
}

#g-other {
  background-color: #0541D8;
}

.subnav-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
}

.subnav:hover #g-videos {
  animation: entranceAnimation .6s forwards;
}

.subnav:hover #g-design {
  animation: entranceAnimation .5s forwards;
}

.subnav:hover #g-other {
  animation: entranceAnimation .4s forwards;
}

@keyframes entranceAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-150%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home" class="navlink">Home</a>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Gallery</button>
    <div class="subnav-content flex">

      <div id="galleries">
        <div id="g-videos" class="gallery">
          <h1><a href="#">Videos</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="g-design" class="gallery">
          <h1><a href="#">Design</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="g-other" class="gallery">
          <h1><a href="#">Other</a></h1>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact" class="navlink">Contact</a>
</div>
```